# HTML - Staying active when invalid entry & click outside

Tags: html, css

My problem is the following. I have a field where a user should be able to enter a number, but only between 0-23. Now If I enter a valid number, it's OK, but when I enter an invalid number and click outside the box, the text moves back to the original place, thus overlaying the user input. How can I fix this so that the text stays up once a number is entered?

```css
#whole {
  bottom: 10px;
}

input {
    width: 295px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
label {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
/* active state */



.highlight {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
    width: 100px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
/* active state */

input:focus ~ .highlight {
    animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
/* ANIMATIONS ================ */

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from {
        background: #5264AE;
    }
    to {
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }
}
input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5264AE;
}
select {
    width: 300px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #999;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}
select:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="whole">
  <form>    
    <div class="group">
      <input type="number" id="hour" min="0" max="23" required>
      <label>Hour of the day (0-23)</label>
    </div>
  </form>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle that with the invalid selector
try adding this to the css

```
input:invalid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}
```

try using the out-of-range selector as suggested by [this article](http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2011/11/28/html5-form-field-validation-with-css3/)

Comment: But if I add that, since the empty input is invalid, too, it just stays up all the time.

Comment: Updated .. hope this helps